# Member based sites security issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi friends I am just wondering what security should i keep in mind when users on my site post anything using form. I have encrypted codeigniter session and also enabled the feature to store session in database, and my example Model function is like this in below. I have enabled form validation and enabled xss and csrf globally.

I think sql injection is automatically handled by CI's active record function. Please suggest me what else do i have to check before taking this site in production. Thanks

```
        function AddSomeMemberPost(){

                $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));

        $data = array(
            'topic' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'status' => 'draft',
            'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('categoryid'),
            'featured' => '0',
            'lang' => $this->input->post('lang'),
                    'pubdate' => $now,
                    'video' => $this->input->post('tube_video'),
                    'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                    'username' => $this->session->userdata('username')
        );

$this->db->insert('my_table', $data);
```

validation are done this way, Do i need to validate session data btw ? It is going thru model.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('topic', 'Topic', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[90]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required|min_length[8]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('tags', 'Tag', 'required|miax_length[50]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('video', 'Youtube Video Link', 'min_length[8]');
```

Comment: we don't see your validations so it's hard to give advices

Comment: added validation please check the edited topic

Comment: you can also add callbacks for some regexs validation of your form post fields

Comment: like described [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you change the PHP error reporting level, which is set in the main /index.php file.

```
error_reporting(0)
```

NOTE: You can set this in a hook instead, so you can leave the standard CI files unchanged.

In general, you should clean ALL data before putting it into any SQL (including data used in a session), even when using the built-in CI DB functions. For example, you should always cast numbers before adding them to SQL

```
$val = (int)$val;
```

(NOTE: For performance you can check if these values are even in a valid range before attempting to run a query, to save yourself from running queries you know will return nothing. For example, if you're searching for a value that is a positive integer, then you don't need to run a query if $val <= 0)